# Mapping source code line number to "printed" page number

Tags: emacs, elisp

Sometimes I search in emacs for some variable then try to find which page should I look for in the printout of the file I have in hand.
Is it possible, given the printing parameters I use, to have emacs show a "virtual" page number that maps to the where the cursor is pointing at?

I am trying to play with the "mode line", given that each printed page has 72 lines, then page number = line_number/72+1.
This did not work though:

```
(setq-default    mode-line-format
         '("" mode-line-modified "" 
           mode-line-buffer-identification "-" 
           "[" mode-name "." mode-line-process "." minor-mode-alist "" "%n" "]" 
           line-number-mode   "-" "L%l" 
           "-" "P" (+ 1 (/ %l 72))
           column-number-mode "-" "C%c" 
           mode-line-misc-info ""
           abbreviated-file-name 
           "%-"
           )
         )
```

Anny pointers?

Comment: How about having the line numbers printed on the printout using something like `(line-number-at-pos)`, or perhaps at the header or footer of the printed page -- e.g., beginning line number ending line number (on a per page basis)?  Something like `(setq ps-right-footer . . .)`

Comment: Good point. However, the code is very busy and very populated, so I rather not waste space on the numbering.

Comment: How about `(message "You are on line %s of page %s." (line-number-at-pos) (+ 1 (/ (line-number-at-pos) 72)) )`

Comment: Paper? Hello from the 21st century; you'll get here eventually.

Comment: tripleee, thanks for your contribution. I work on very complex architecture/coding which is best viewed and understood when printing on paper and then use annotations and markings to make it less ambiguous. Afterwards, changing the code is easier through emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force mode-line updates `(force-mode-line-update)` with something like the `post-command-hook`.

```
(setq-default mode-line-format '(
  " "
  (:eval (format "Line %s | Page %s"
    (line-number-at-pos) (+ 1 (/ (line-number-at-pos) 72)) ))))
```

Comment: lawlist, there a small problem. The printed pages could have the line "wrapped" where it is not in the source code. This will add a line to the printed page that wont be accounted for using the formula above.
Is there an emacs variable that gives the line number "if there was a word wrapping of 80 characters - for example"?
I think that would be a more accurate variable to use instead of line-number-at-pos.

Comment: My first thought would be to have your line length in the master file be shorter such that it never wraps when printed, or shrink the font on the printout so that it doesn't wrap when printed.  Or, you could use landscape instead of portrait when printing; or, you could adjust the margins to permit more text in portrait mode.